# No [EntityType] was found for the key class [] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [EntityType] was found for the key class [] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>  </class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entityEmbeddableManagedTypeNotFound(MetamodelImpl.java:173)
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="temp_param")
public class ParamConfiguration implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "param_group")
private String paramGroup;
public String getParamGroup() {
    return paramGroup;
}
public void setParamGroup(String paramGroup) {
    this.paramGroup = paramGroup;
}
```

DAO code:

```
 CriteriaQuery<ParamConfiguration> cq = entityManager
                .getCriteriaBuilder()
                .createQuery(ParamConfiguration.class);
     final Root<ParamConfiguration> ac = cq.from(ParamConfiguration.class);
     cq.select(ac);
     TypedQuery<ParamConfiguration> tq=entityManager.createQuery(cq);
     List<ParamConfiguration> AClist=tq.getResultList();
```

persistance xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="serCoupons_Cdm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/CDM</non-jta-data-source>


    <class>net.odcorp.sas.mrm.beans.AffinityConfiguration</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Can anyone help me on this.... Is the @entity class must have all the columns in the DB table.

FYI im using Teradata as DB, Spring, JPA, JSF.

Comment: i don't see you are mapping your Entity class ParamConfiguration in persistence.xml, however you can have fields in your Entity which does not have equivalent in Database, but they need to be annotated with @Transient

Comment: Oh, your peristence file must be `persistence.xml`, not persistance.xml

Comment: I get this error only when I run `java -jar something.jar`. It works fine when I run it in cloudFoundry or `mvn springboot run`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ParamConfiguration` entity is not listed in the persistence.xml file and you set the option `exclude-unlisted-classes` to `true`

add this to your persistence.xml file :

```
<class>net.odcorp.sas.mrm.beans.ParamConfiguration</class>
```

be sure that the package is ok.

Comment: Setting `exclude-unlisted-classes` to true will not pick up all annotated entity classes.

Comment: It's not working... Is it mandatory to add all columns in table to Entity class

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your persistence.xml file,

```
<persistence-unit name="serCoupons_Cdm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>jdbc/CDM</non-jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false<exclude-unlisted-classes/>
```

`exclude-unlisted-classes` has true as it's default value. or if its set to true, then you need to specify the  tag manually to list the entity class,

```
<class>com.package.Class</class>
```

Comment: "<exclude-unlisted-classes>false<exclude-unlisted-classes/>" ???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in my case I was missing the 
@Table annotation. Also in my code  don't use @Column annotation, I use @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY) right below @Id. It works for me without using

```
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

I can provide my source code since I've just been using to learn about JPA.